# Is SUBSTRING the fastest way to get individual bytes on a Microsoft Sql Server Binary field?

Tags: sql-server, performance, substring

I know the most common way is to use `SUBSTRING`, but is there a faster way to get a single `byte` at a given index, on a `binary(n)` field?

Comment: Do you *need* a faster way? Have you, in *profiling* your code, and comparing it's performance against your performance *goals*, established that `SUBSTRING` is the bottleneck?

Comment: Why would you assume that I have a bottleneck and that anyone should be comfortable with a solution when they are uncertain if a better one exists? I don't have a bottleneck. I am checking the uniqueness of a GUID within 100 million GUID rows in a table, in 0.05 milliseconds. But a part of my function involves using substring to get the single byte at a specific array index. Substring makes me feel like it was optimized for strings and does not give me confidence that it is purely the fasted way to do it.

Comment: If you entire process (whatever it is) takes two hours to run, and `SUBSTRING` versus whatever you replace it with changes the timings by 0.01 seconds, was it really worth optimizing *that* part of your process? Also, if you check the *documentation* for `SUBSTRING`, you'll see that it's very clearly *specified* in how it works with binary - it's not some kind of "hack" to use it for extracting bytes.

Comment: If the entire process takes two hours to run, and in five years your company grows 100,000 times larger, which solution should you choose? You are trying to void the question by making business assumptions, about a business you do not know. Answer the question or don't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

String.charAt(n) or String.toBytes()[n].

When working with string, you need to consider some characters have multiple bytes encoding.

Comment: There is no charAt in Sql Server but I failed to specify in the question. I'd better edit that.

Comment: why not doing it in Java? Is there a reason why you must do it in the SQL server?

Comment: @MinhKieu - if you have, say, 2GB of data stored in a column in SQL, and you want to extract the 45th byte, it would be *extremely* inefficient to transfer the full 2GB across from the server just to have the "convenience" of using the Java methods.

Comment: 2GB text storing as CLOB? hmm. You extract it and updating it as well?

Comment: "If I don't know how to do it this way then why don't I just move it to a different environment where I can do it how I already know" -this is why we don't outsource.